# Replacing jumper wire on thermostat

Tags: thermostat

My intention is to remove a Nest Thermostat and reconnect the old thermostat. However, I have misplaced the red jumper wire.

A rep at Home Depot suggested an 18 gauge wire would work. Here are 2 helpful pics. Is 18 gauge the right gauge to use?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, #18 is fine, it would serve no purpose to be any larger than the wire connecting the stat to the air handling equipment.

Comment: If you have slack you could even trim a piece of the existing wire.

Comment: Wish I had thought of that earlier!